# How do I show a tooltip on hovering over a star rating lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript, lightning-experience, lightning-apps

I have this star rating lightning component. I need to show a tooltip that shows the number of the star that the cursor is on and not the rating that is selected. I know I can get the value of rating and show that but I don't want that. I am open to changing my code to change the value of the rating onhover instead of onclick if that would make it easier/better.

[image: ScreenShot of Test App]

```
<aura:component description="StarRating">
<aura:attribute name='value' type='Integer' default='0' />
<aura:attribute name='readonly' type='boolean' default='false' />
<aura:registerEvent name="DummyEvent" type="akritiv:DummyEvent"/>

<ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.fivestar + '/rating.css'}"
              scripts="{!$Resource.fivestar + '/rating.js'}"
              afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.afterScriptsLoaded}" />


    <aura:handler name='change' value="{!v.value}" action="{!c.onValueChange}" />

   <p class="rating"> <div class="slds-text-heading_small">Rating</div></p> 
       <ul aura:id='ratingArea' class="{!v.readonly ? 'readonly c-rating' : 'c-rating' }" />



</aura:component>
```

JS Controller

```
({
    afterScriptsLoaded : function(component, event, helper) {
        var domEl = component.find("ratingArea").getElement();
        console.log('domEl>>>'+JSON.stringify(domEl));
        var currentRating = component.get('v.value');
        console.log('currentRating>>>'+currentRating);
        var readOnly = component.get('v.readonly');
        console.log('readOnly>>>'+readOnly);
        var maxRating = 5;
        var callback = function(rating) {
            component.set('v.value',rating);
        }
        component.ratingObj = rating(domEl,currentRating,maxRating,callback,readOnly);
    },

    onValueChange: function(component,event,helper) {
        if (component.ratingObj) {
            var value = component.get('v.value');

            var v =component.ratingObj.domEl;
            console.log('v'+v);
            component.ratingObj.setRating(value,false);
            var cmpEvent = component.getEvent("DummyEvent");
            cmpEvent.setParams({"getRatingvalue" : value });
            cmpEvent.fire();
        }
    },

})
```

Comment: Welcome!  Can you please edit your post to show your code more clearly?  Also, I don't see the actual markup for the 5 stars component you're showing.

Comment: I've edited the post now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For easy tooltip hovers, consider using `<lightning:helptext>`, which you can read about [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:helptext/example)

You can also just leverage the `title` element attribute on `<li>` to show the number after hovering for a couple seconds

Comment: The problem is that if I select a value for eg. 3. I can show that in the helptext. But I want to show the star number when I hover over a particular star. For eg. If I hover over the 4th star I should see 4 on the tooltip and not 3.

Comment: Try just using the `title` attribute on the <li> element.  If you hover for a couple seconds, it should show up, like any other element